# Gulp isn't running while using bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, gulp

[TEMPLATE USING](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/argon-dashboard#)

For recreating the problem

1. Download the Template
2. NPM INSTALL
3. GULP

Error

```
    [14:27:04] Using gulpfile ~/Downloads/argon-dashboard-master/gulpfile.js
[14:27:04] Starting 'default'...
[14:27:04] Starting 'scss'...
(node:47598) [DEP0097] DeprecationWarning: Using a domain property in MakeCallback is deprecated. Use the async_context variant of MakeCallback or the AsyncResource class instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
WARNING: `text-emphasis-variant()` has been deprecated as of v4.4.0. It will be removed entirely in v5.
         on line 8 of assets/scss/bootstrap/mixins/_deprecate.scss, in mixin `deprecate`
         from line 16 of assets/scss/bootstrap/mixins/_text-emphasis.scss, in mixin `text-emphasis-variant`
         from line 48 of assets/scss/core/utilities/_text.scss
         from line 28 of assets/scss/custom/_utilities.scss
         from line 70 of assets/scss/argon.scss

WARNING: `text-emphasis-variant()` has been deprecated as of v4.4.0. It will be removed entirely in v5.
         on line 8 of assets/scss/bootstrap/mixins/_deprecate.scss, in mixin `deprecate`
         from line 16 of assets/scss/bootstrap/mixins/_text-emphasis.scss, in mixin `text-emphasis-variant`
         from line 48 of assets/scss/core/utilities/_text.scss
         from line 28 of assets/scss/custom/_utilities.scss
         from line 70 of assets/scss/argon.scss

WARNING: `text-emphasis-variant()` has been deprecated as of v4.4.0. It will be removed entirely in v5.
         on line 8 of assets/scss/bootstrap/mixins/_deprecate.scss, in mixin `deprecate`
         from line 16 of assets/scss/bootstrap/mixins/_text-emphasis.scss, in mixin `text-emphasis-variant`
         from line 48 of assets/scss/core/utilities/_text.scss
         from line 28 of assets/scss/custom/_utilities.scss
         from line 70 of assets/scss/argon.scss

WARNING: `text-emphasis-variant()` has been deprecated as of v4.4.0. It will be removed entirely in v5.
         on line 8 of assets/scss/bootstrap/mixins/_deprecate.scss, in mixin `deprecate`
         from line 16 of assets/scss/bootstrap/mixins/_text-emphasis.scss, in mixin `text-emphasis-variant`
         from line 48 of assets/scss/core/utilities/_text.scss
         from line 28 of assets/scss/custom/_utilities.scss
         from line 70 of assets/scss/argon.scss

[14:27:07] Finished 'scss' after 3.78 s
[14:27:07] Starting 'browserSync'...
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3002
    External: http://192.168.1.45:3002
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3003
 UI External: http://localhost:3003
```

and When I open the port I am getting

Cannot get /

currently using

node --version:- v14.5.0

gulp --version
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2

Using ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: it just says its a warning but it finishes. Did you test it tho?

Comment: yeap i did is it running for you ? on localhost

Comment: I am getting 'cannot get /' on port